# Error while installing v7 app compact library

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to install v7 app compact library in my Xamarin studio but having some not installed error:

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

My project target Android version : Android5.1(Api Level 22 )

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a version error. So you should try the following :

1. Clean your project
2. Type this into the Package Manager Console

   ```
   Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
   ```
3. I suppose you tried, but in case you didn't, go check the NuGet Package Manager (Right-click on your project, "Manage NuGet Package")
4. If this doesn't work, try to get it from here :
   https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportv7appcompat
5. Eventually, try to change your project target version or to install the package in a new project of the same version
6. If none of the above helped, you'll need to provide more informations for us to help you.

(The source of the command)
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/